# Pagination library in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

This is my config:

```
$config['pagination'] = array( 
    'page_query_string' => TRUE,
    'query_string_segment' => 'page',
    'full_tag_open' => '<div id="page_footer">',
    'full_tag_close' => '</div>',
    'anchor_class' => 'class="pagecurrent"',
    //'next_link' => '&raquo;',
    //'prev_link' => '&laquo;',
    'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
    'last_link' => 'Trang cuối',
    'first_link' => 'Trang đầu',
    'num_links' => 4,
);
```

Controller:

```
$this->pagination->initialize(
                    array_merge(
                        $this->config->item('pagination'),
                        array(
                            'total_rows' => $this->_data['total_quizs'],
                            'per_page' => BE_QUIZ_PER_PAGE,
                            'base_url' => base_url()
                        )
                    )
                );
                $this->_data['pageination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

When i run it, i got this link:

http://quiz.com/&page=2

Link wrong, should have http://quiz.com/?page=2, so i edit base_url config become

**base_url() . '? '**

It's work well, but when i click to page 2, link go back page 1 become http://quiz.com/?&page=2?&page=

i was update new version CI. By the way, i want to ask a question, i want to use page_query_string for this case http://quiz.com?page=x, how to config this.

Answer (score 0):

true the $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
and add

base_url()."?a=1";
For a time being it will help you to do what you want.

Comment: No, segment only apply for page_query_string is false (ex: http://quiz.com/x) this case, segment is 1. Now, i want to use page_query_string is true, this case it's display http://quiz.com?page=x

Comment: then save the baseURL and edit remove the last / from string 
$url=base_url();
$url=substr($url,0,-1);